# Magento2 alertifyjs integration

Tags: magento2, alertifyjs

We have to integrate alertifyjs to magento2 integration, please find the below link http://alertifyjs.com/

all magento2 alerts should be in the above link

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify `requirejs-config.js` in your theme, just add new entry in shim if exists or create key shim in config.

```js
var config = {
    "shim": {
        "js/alertify.min": []
    }
};
```

2. Add script under you theme js path
3. Use it by requiring dependency in require wherever you need it.